# Docker on ubuntu app for windows 10 starting but not running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a windows 10 enterprise laptop.
Installing docker on that machine in the past proved unsuccessful.

As an alternative I have installed the ubuntu app from microsoft store, ubuntu version Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I then followed the tutorial to install docker ce on ubuntu and everything went smoothly up to running an app.

I installed Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77

I did the post-installation for unix, logout using exit and restarted.

It looks like I can start docker:

```
~$ sudo service docker start
* Starting Docker: docker
```

But when checking if docker is running for real, it seems that it is not the case:

```
~$ ps
PID TTY     TIME CMD
4   tty1    00:00:00 bash
328 tty1    00:00:00 ps
```

It is confirmed with the error message when running the hello world image:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Is there specificity with Ubuntu app for windows that prevent me from running docker?

Edit: thanks to @atline link, it is mentioned windows does not support running docker daemon within the WSL.

I cannot run docker desktop and hit a wall on below issue closed without being resolved:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/74

Comment: Add user to docker group "sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)" then log off or restart the machine.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1352813/does-the-wsl-from-windows-10-spring-update-2018-allows-me-to-run-docker-on-it, helpful?

Comment: have you found a solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin"

alias docker=docker.exe

alias docker-compose=docker-compose.exe